# How to send hard coded string from Android APP when button is pressed to a UDP listener in Node-Red?

Tags: android, udp

**OVERVIEW**

I'm using Android Studio to make an app that on a button press sends a string to a UDP listener in Node-Red running on my laptop, Node-Red filters anything that comes in and function nodes do their thing. This app will work inside a LAN not over the internet.

So far I have made a new project with an empty activity and my activity_main.xml has the button. There is no need for the user to input a string/text so the button press code will have the "string" and Node-Red listener IP and port hard coded.

There is also no need to receive a reply from the laptop/node-red side so the button press should be a fire and forget hard coded message hence UDP and not a TCP socket.

**QUESTION**

What code is required for the MainActivity to send the string when the button is pressed to the UDP listener in Node-Red?

I have spent a long time scouring the internet for answers and tried many code examples however they have not worked. A lot of the research I've seen is people with UDP receive problems, however I cannot understand their code for sending UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out with a ridiculous amount of trial and error... please see the code below if anyone else ever gets the same problem:

```
//On button press the message is sent via UDP
    findViewById(R.id.btSendMessage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int txnumber = Integer.parseInt(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.transmitnumber)).getText().toString());
            String data = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttosend)).getText().toString();
            int port = Integer.valueOf(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverport)).getText().toString());
            String address = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverip)).getText().toString();
            SendData(txnumber, data, port, address);

        }
    });



private DatagramSocket UDPSocket;
private InetAddress address;
private int port;

public void Theaddress(InetAddress address) {
    try {
        this.UDPSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.address = address;
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void SendInstruction(final byte[] data, final int port) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
                UDPSocket.send(packet);
                DatagramPacket packetreponse = null;
                UDPSocket.receive(packetreponse);
                DisplayData(packetreponse);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void SendData(final int nbRepet, final String Sdata , final int port, final String address) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Theaddress(InetAddress.getByName(address));
                for (int i = 0; i < nbRepet; i++) {
                    byte[] data = Sdata.getBytes();
                    SendInstruction(data,port);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void ReceiveData(final int portNum) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final int tally = 1024;
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[tally];
                DatagramSocket socketReceive = new DatagramSocket(portNum);
                while (true) {
                    DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                    socketReceive.receive(data);
                    DisplayData(data);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void DisplayData(DatagramPacket data) {
    System.out.println(data);
}
```